# React js using useState Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to use useState react hook as follows,

```
 const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
    function handleClick(){
        setShowMore(true);
    }
```

I pass my wishlistItemCount value to WishlistItems component

```
const wishListItemCount = showMore ? itemsCount : 3;
   const contentMessageElement =
        <WishlistItems
            itemCount={wishListItemCount}
            wishlistId={data.id}
            items={items}/>
```

I use following button to change the state

```
           <Button
                onClick={handleClick}
                className={classes.btnshowmore}>Show More
             </Button>
```

But I get the error when I load the page

```
Storybook preview hooks can only be called inside decorators and story functions.
```

Please help

My Full component

```
import React,{ useCallback } from 'react';
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client';

import {FormattedMessage, useIntl} from 'react-intl';
import {ChevronDown, ChevronUp, MoreHorizontal} from 'react-feather';
import {useWishlist} from '@magento/peregrine/lib/talons/WishlistPage/useWishlist';

import {mergeClasses} from '@magento/venia-ui/lib/classify';
import Icon from '../Icon';
import WishlistItems from './wishlistItems';
import defaultClasses from './wishlist.css';
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";
import {useWishlistAllItems} from "./useWishlistAllItems";
import wishlistItemOperations from "./wishlistItem.gql";
import {useCartContext} from "@magento/peregrine/lib/context/cart";
import {Link} from "../../drivers";
import {useState} from "@storybook/addons";


const Wishlist = props => {
    const {data} = props;
    const {formatMessage} = useIntl();
    const {
        items_count: itemsCount,
        items: items,
        name,
        sharing_code: sharingCode
    } = data;


    const talProps = useWishlistAllItems({
        items,
        ...wishlistItemOperations
    });
    const {
        handleAddAllItemsToCart,
        saveWishList,
        hasError,
        isLoading
    } = talProps;

    const talonProps = useWishlist();
    const {isOpen} = talonProps;
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
    function handleClick(){
        setShowMore(true);
    }

    const wishListItemCount = showMore ? itemsCount : 3;


    const classes = mergeClasses(defaultClasses, props.classes);
    const contentClass = isOpen ? classes.content : classes.content_hidden;
    const visibilityLabel = sharingCode
        ? formatMessage({id: 'wishlist.publicText', defaultMessage: 'Public'})
        : formatMessage({
            id: 'wishlist.privateText',
            defaultMessage: 'Private'
        });


    const contentMessageElement = itemsCount ? (
        <WishlistItems
            itemCount={wishListItemCount}
            wishlistId={data.id}
            items={items}/>
    ) : (
        <p>
            <FormattedMessage
                id={'wishlist.emptyListText'}
                defaultMessage={'There are currently no items in this list'}
            />
        </p>
    );

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <div className={classes.header}>
                <div className={classes.nameContainer}>
                    <h2 className={classes.name}>{name}</h2>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.subname}>
                    <span className={classes.visibility}>
                        {visibilityLabel}
                    </span>
                    <a className={classes.seeall}>See all</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.tableheadroot}>
                <p className={classes.th1}>Product Information</p>
                <p className={classes.th2}>Put in the Basket</p>
            </div>
            <div className={contentClass}>{contentMessageElement}</div>
            <div className={classes.showmore}>
                <Button
                    onClick={handleClick}
                    className={classes.btnshowmore}>Show More</Button>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.btnsetbottom}>
                <Link to={'/share-wishlist'}>
                <Button className={classes.btnsharewishlist}>
                    Share your wish list
                </Button>
                </Link>
                <Button
                    className={classes.btnsharewishlist}
                    onClick={handleAddAllItemsToCart}>
                    Put all the goods in basket
                </Button>
                <Button
                    onclick={saveWishList}
                    className={classes.btnsharewishlist}>
                    Save your wish list
                </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Wishlist;
```

Comment: <Button onClick={handleClick} ...

Comment: @Roy.B does'nt make any difference

Comment: Are you using a story in your storybook to show your new component? The problem looks like a storybook config problem, also Roy.B has a point in the onClick event from the button you should pass the reference or a function onClick={handleClick} or onClick={()=>handleClick()}

Comment: button click is not the issue.I have no idea about the storybooks

Comment: Please could you share your story?

Comment: @SahanThilakarathna fixing the onClick is the start if you want help with  storybook, share your code regarding the storybook implementation you made

Comment: what is the story?I have no idea.please explain

Comment: in StoryBook, you should create a Story for each component you want to show, those stories are the space where you import your component and configure an example to show others how to use it. looks this doc https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/introduction

Comment: The problem is not in your component, in this case, the message "Storybook preview hooks ..." point me to your storybook configuration

Comment: @SahanThilakarathna change this import {useState} from "@storybook/addons";
to this import {useAddonState} from "@storybook/addons"; for more info see https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/addons-api#useaddonstate

Comment: I think I have fixed the issue.The problem was with the import of useState.I have used
import { useState } from 'react';
instead of the
import {useState} from "@storybook/addons";

Comment: @Roy.B can you tell me how to pass wishListItemCount to my child component on button click.Changed value is not passed to the child component.

Comment: @SahanThilakarathna const [showMoreWishList, setShowMoreWishList] = useAddonState(data.id, false);                                                             function handleClick(){
        setShowMore(true);                
        setShowMoreWishList(true);
    }

Comment: @Roy.B sorry I didn't get it.I'm using useState() hook.

Comment: @Roy.B solved that issue too thank you

Answer (score 34):

try changing

```
import {useState} from "@storybook/addons";
```

to

```
import {useState} from "react";
```

Comment: I had this problem, is there any reason to import it from there?

Comment: I've been looking high and low for the answer. Damn auto-complete.

Comment: it's VS code IntelliSense, thanks for the help

Comment: I need to do the opposite to make this work :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

```
           <Button
                onClick={handleClick}
                className={classes.btnshowmore}>Show More
             </Button>
```

there is different in html events and react.

[document description](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: does'nt make any difference I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues here, button on click invoke on render and you need to use storybook state to pass state changes

```
const [showMoreWishList, setShowMoreWishList] = useAddonState(data.id, false); 
  ...

function handleClick(){ 
  setShowMore(true); 
  setShowMoreWishList(true); 
}
 ...

  <Button 
    onClick={handleClick}
 ...
```